# Get list from the table matching a character or a string

Tags: mysql

How could I make a query that will return results where `username`:

- Either starts with `o`
- Either Contains `o` somewhere in between
- Either ends with `o`

I was trying:

```
select username from userinfo where username in('%o' , '%o%' , '%o')
```

But the above query doesn't return any result. What could be the reason for this? How could I get the result?

Comment: You have to use `LIKE`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos `Error Code : 1241
Operand should contain 1 column(s)` Got this error

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `LIKE`:

```
select username 
from userinfo 
where username LIKE '%o' OR username LIKE '%o%' OR username LIKE '%o'
```

Alternatively, if you don't have a bit data set and are looking for a more succinct syntax you can use [**`REPLACE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
select username 
from userinfo 
where REPLACE(username, 'o', '') <> username
```

Comment: You guys are wizards. I couldn't answer quick enough

Comment: Isn't `in` meant to do this job?

Comment: In is used to check if the string is inside another array, you use subqueries on it. To compare string equivalency you need like.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you need the [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) operator:

```
SELECT username
FROM userinfo
WHERE 
username LIKE '%o'  OR
username LIKE '%o%' OR
username LIKE '%o
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select username 
from userinfo  
where username like '%o'  
OR username like '%o%'  
OR username like '%o';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using [REGEXP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm)

```
select username 
from userinfo 
WHERE username REGEXP 'o'
```

or like

```
SELECT username FROM userinfo WHERE find_in_set('o', username)>0
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to improve thinking

Contains `o` somewhere in between covers both start and end. So you need only

```
select username from userinfo where username like '%o%'
```